# Euler's Numerical method help

Tags: mathematica, project-euler

> Consider this differential equation,
>
> $dy/dx = x + \sin(y)$
>
> with initial condition $y = 0.5$ when $x = 1.2$:
>
> 1. Write down the recurrence relation for Euler's numerical method
>      applied above.
> 2. With step size h = 0.1, calculate the approximations to y(1.3) and
>      y(1.4).

1. This is my answer:

   $$Y_i+1 = Y_i + 0.1(X_i + \sin(Y_i))$$
2. I have problem solving this one...

   From my txtbk reference, I sub $i = 1$ into the eqn thus giving me

   $Y_1 = Y_0 + 0.1(1.2 + \sin(0.5))    = 0.1679$

   Then, $i = 2$

   $Y_2 = Y_1 + 0.1(1.3 + \sin(0.6)$

Im sure my method in part 2 is wrong and I don't really understand how to solve it via my txtbk.

Comment: The method y(i+1)=y(i)+hf(x(i),y(i)),where dy/dx=f(x,y), you applied, seems to be correct at first sight, provided the calculations are correct of course! However using Taylor series expansion, one can show that the error term       e(i)= 1+h(del f /del y) at (x(i),y(i)) (here del stands for partial derivative), whose absolute value must be <1 for successive errors to damp out. So please check whether that condition is satisfied, else take into consideration the error terms in each iteration.

Comment: Do you really intend the "project-euler" tag? Project Euler $\ne$ Euler's method!

Answer (score 1):

We have the differential equation  $ y'(x) = x + \sin(y)$ with initial condition $y(1.2) = 0.5$.

Euler's method states that we may approximate the value of the function at $y(x+\delta x)$ for some 'small step' $\delta x$ by assuming the function is approximately linear between $x$ and $x+\delta x$. I.e:

$$y(x+\delta x) \approx y(x) + y'(x)\cdot \delta x $$

Thus, for a step size of $\delta x = 0.1$, starting at $x=1.2$ we would have:

$$y(1.2+0.1)  \approx  y(1.2) + y'(1.2)\cdot 0.1 $$
$$y(1.3) = 0.5 + (1.2+\sin(0.5))\cdot 0.1$$
$$ = 0.5 + 0.167942554 $$

So you dropped the $0.5$ term in your calculation, i.e - what you call $Y_0$. 
Hopefully this makes things clearer for you. Can you figure out $y(1.4)$ now?

Comment: y(1.3+0.1)≈y(1.3)+y′(1.3)⋅0.1
y(1.4)=0.6679+0.1(1.3+sin(0.6679))
=0.859880

Comment: @Gigili, I think upvoting takes some number of points, but accepting is certainly an option.